# Postgres distinct rows whilst also summing

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, psql

I have a dataset that is similar to this. I need to pick out the most recent metadata (greater execution time = more recent) for a client  including the sum of quantities and the latest execution time and meta where the quantity > 0

```
| Name     | Quantity | Metadata | Execution time |
| -------- | ---------|----------|----------------|
| Neil     | 1        | [1,3]    |  4             |
| James    | 1        | [2,18]   |  5             |
| Neil     | 1        | [4, 1]   |  6             |
| Mike     | 1        | [5, 42]  |  7             |
| James    | -1       | Null     |  8             |
| Neil     | -1       | Null     |  9             |
```

Eg the query needs to return:

```
| Name     | Summed Quantity | Metadata | Execution time |
| -------- | ----------------|----------|----------------|
| James    | 0               | [2,18]   |  5             |
| Neil     | 1               | [4, 1]   |  6             |
| Mike     | 1               | [5, 42]  |  7             |
```

My query doesn't quite work as it's not returning the sum of the quantities correctly.

```
SELECT 

distinct on (name) name, 
(
    SELECT 
      cast(
        sum(quantity) as int
        
      )
  ) as summed_quantity,
     
  meta,
  execution_time  
FROM 
  table 
where 
 quantity > 0
group by 
  name,  
  meta, 
  execution_time 
order by 
  name, 
  execution_time desc;
```

This query gives a result of

```
| Name     | Summed Quantity | Metadata | Execution time |
| -------- | ----------------|----------|----------------|
| James    | 1               | [2,18]   |  5             |
| Neil     | 1               | [4, 1]   |  6             |
| Mike     | 1               | [5, 42]  |  7             |
```

ie it's just taking the quantity > 0 from the where and not adding up the quantities in the sub query (i assume because of the distinct clause) I'm unsure how to fix my query to produce the desired output.

Comment: how will you compute "**most recent**" without a timestamp? (or, perhaps an automatic id when row is inserted?)

Comment: badly written explanation. For most recent it's the greatest execution time. I'll edit.

Comment: Your subquery has no FROM or WHERE.  So of course it takes quantity from the outer query, where else would it get it from?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using window functions (hence with a single pass of the data)

```
select
       name
     , sum_qty
     , metadata
     , execution_time
from (
     select 
            *
          , sum(Quantity) over(partition by name) sum_qty
          , row_number() over(partition by name, case when quantity > 0 then 1 else 0 end
                              order by Execution_time DESC) as rn
     from mytable
     ) d
where rn = 1 and quantity > 0
order by name
```

**result**

```
+-------+---------+----------+----------------+
| name  | sum_qty | metadata | execution_time |
+-------+---------+----------+----------------+
| James |       0 | [2,18]   |              5 |
| Mike  |       1 | [5,42]   |              7 |
| Neil  |       1 | [4,1]    |              6 |
+-------+---------+----------+----------------+
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=64186fd8f6ab2136403f864046cf1ecb)*

Comment: I'm looking to sum all of their quantities. So the sum_qty column in this case is incorrect. I have to get last meta for a user when the quantity was > 0 but also some all of their entries (even when negative) ie James should return 0.

Comment: I have amended the query in response to your comment, now the row numbering s divided into groups based on +/- qty and then filtered out in outer query